# Online payment - check provision

Tags: stripe-payments, payment-gateway

I'm developing a Symfony 3 application and the client chooses stripe for online payment

Users will make auctions on the website.

Is there a solution (with stripe or another system) to check if the user has provision on his account to accept the auction ?

Amounts can be quite big (10k€)

Thanks !
Olivia

Answer (score 3):

A lot of payment gateways offer Auth/Capture separation, in which you can first authorize the payment (suggesting the shopper's credit card has enough in the CC cap\credit ceiling to afford this deal **currently**).

The issue is that this authorisation request often puts the funds on a "hold period" on the card - a time frame in which the CC cap is reduced as if the shopper purchased the item, and could cause the shopper to max-out their credit even if they didn't end up purchasing. This is why authorisation calls on large amounts need to be handled with caution.

If you want to go ahead with this business model, make sure you also have a cancel/reverse authorisation option - that will allow you to validate first with an auth only request, and then release the hold on the shopper's CC. I am not familiar with Stripe's API, but I know that BlueSnap has both Auth and Auth reversal APIs:

Auth API: https://developers.bluesnap.com/v8976-JSON/docs/auth-only

Auth reversal API: https://developers.bluesnap.com/v8976-JSON/docs/auth-reversal

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [auth & capture](https://stripe.com/docs/charges#auth-and-capture) flow to create an authorization but not capture the funds immediately.

Note that such large amounts will probably have high decline rates. I recommend you reach out to Stripe's support at https://support.stripe.com/email to discuss your business model in more details.